# from active div how to filter the dynamically div based on multiple selections

Tags: javascript, jquery

[by default displayed record, data should be displayed based on multiple check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH4XD.png)

Hi, I need help, I am new for frontend, I have record displayed in unordered, all records are having a class name. and another div have the list of multiple choice, from there I am passing class name, So I want to record should be displayed dynamically based on selection

am facing the problem to sorting the divs,I am new in fronted side, please any one can help.thanks

below is my problem
example:

```
<div class="main>

    <div class="aa"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="zz"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="cc"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="aa"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="bb"> data elements or contents</div>

</div>
```

====and in another div i have multiple choice option from there i can pass the class name or id if that id or classname are mathe in main div then child div content should be arraenged in that order===

if first i selected call aa then bb, so immediate result should be as below=====

```
<div class="main>
    <div class="aa"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="aa"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="bb"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="zz"> data elements or contents</div>
    <div class="cc"> data elements or contents</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to share some code (CSS, JS & HTML), so that we can help you out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try  like this

```
$(function() {
  $(".main div").sort(sort_div).appendTo('.listitems');
  function sort_div(a, b) {
    //your sorting logic
    return ($(b).attr('class')) < ($(a).attr('class')) ? 1 : -1;
  }
});
```